# Let $ G $ satisfying the maximal permutizer condition, then $ G/N $ satisfying the maximal permutizer condition ?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $ H $ be a proper subgroup of finite group $ G $. Then permutizer $ H $ in $ G $ is defined by $ P_{G}(H) = \langle y \in G \vert \langle y \rangle H = H \langle y \rangle \rangle $. A group $ G $ is said to satisfy the permutizer condition in $ G $ if $ H < P_{G}(H) $. And A group $ G $ is said to satisfy the maximal permutizer condition if $ P_{G}(M) = G $ for any maximal subgroup $ M $ of $ G $. Let $ G $ satisfying the maximal permutizer condition and $ N $ is normal subgroup of $ G $, then $ G/N $ satisfying the maximal permutizer condition ?

Comment: Yes that's right - the proof is routine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ M/N $ maximal subgroup of $ G/N $. Since $ M $ maximal subgroup of $ G $ and $ N $ subgroup of $ M $, Then $ P_{G/N}(M/N) = P_{G}(M)/N = G/N $. This means $ G/N $ satisfying maximal permutizer condition.